What is wrong with this use of robocopy
I want to sync these 2 folders
I do
robocopy "arbitrage3" "arbitrage4" /z /xo
robocopy "arbitrage4" "arbitrage3" /z /xo

echo Sync Complete

pause (It prevents the console window from closing after executing the command.)

And some files are simply not copied.
Files that don't exist in arbitrage4 is not copied from arbitrage3
I think it used to work.
I tried deleting EVERYTHING from arbitrage4
and then do robocopy again
This is what I got
NOTHING is copied
C:\Users\TeguhProg\Dropbox>robocopy "arbitrage3" "arbitrage4" /xo

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thursday, August 1, 2024 8:21:04 PM
   Source : C:\Users\TeguhProg\Dropbox\arbitrage3\
     Dest : C:\Users\TeguhProg\Dropbox\arbitrage4\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /XO /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                         215    C:\Users\TeguhProg\Dropbox\arbitrage3\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :       215         0       215         0         0         0
   Bytes :  251.54 m         0  251.54 m         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Ended : Thursday, August 1, 2024 8:21:04 PM


According to the robocopy documentation, when you add /xo, the source directory files older than the destination are excluded from the copy. This might result in the loss of synchronization. If you looking for other options, /copyall might do the magic for you as it copies all the information supposedly without taking care whether the file is present or not.
